# Javascript rotate image with mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, rotation, mouse-position, mouse-coordinates, parallax

Im using a parallax effect that moves a ball according to the users mouse position (http://webdev.stephband.info/jparallax/index.html). I am trying to figure out a way that the ball will also rotate. So it would appear that as the user moves their mouse over the area, the ball rolls across the screen.

I have found some javascript examples that show how to rotate an item on mouse click, I am just not skiled enough in js to put it all together.

here is a Jsfiddle that shows an example:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xV7v/)

Answer (score 1):

This is more tangential advice than an answer, but in order to make the rolling ball look realistic, make sure that it rotates at a rate that is consistent with the ball's circumference. Otherwise it will look fakey.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This jQuery plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples) might be useful.

Comment: None of those examples work in Firefox 4, and the page is riddled with script errors.

Comment: I have similar issues in FF3.6. Thats good guidance though, if I can figure out how to line it up with the speed of the parallax